# Templates dropdown not appearing using _s theme (underscores)

Tags: theme-development, templates, page-template, dropdown

I am currently using _s via http://underscores.me/ and am trying to add a new page template... I should be able to just add this new page template in the root of my theme, correct? Or should I be create a page-templates folder?

I have tried something as simple as:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Front Page
 */
?>
```

But, the Templates selection dropdown is not appearing when I try to add a new page.

Using WordPress 4.6.1 and Underscores.me most latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a really trivial thing, in the end. My template file was not saved with a .php extension. It's always the little things!!